# How do you distinguish ferrocene, acetylferrocene and diacetylferrocene in a NMR spectra?

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, nmr-spectroscopy

I made an experiment where I made a Friedel-Crafts acetylation of ferrocene. Now I would like to know if/how I can distinguish ferrocene, acetylferrocene and diacetylferrocene in a NMR spectra? For my reaction I used ferrocene, acetic anhydride and phosphoric acid.

Comment: The presence of the methyl singlet from the acetyl group at 2.4 is pretty diagnostic and its intergration against the ferrocene protons will tell you whether there are 1 or 2 acetyls present

Comment: Can you show the NMR spectrum, and also how much you have been able to analyze the peaks?

Answer (score 2):

$\mathrm{^1H \ NMR}$ spectra of pure ferrocene, acetylferrocene, and diacetylferrocene are very distinguishable:

- $\mathrm{^1H \ NMR}$ spectrum of ferrocene consists of only a singlet at $\approx \pu{4.2 ppm}$.
- $\mathrm{^1H \ NMR}$ spectrum of acetylferrocene consists of 4 signals: a triplet or multiplet around $\pu{4.8 ppm} \ \ce{(2H)},$ a triplet or multiplet around $\pu{4.5 ppm} \ \ce{(2H)},$ a singlet around $\pu{4.2 ppm} \ \ce{(5H)},$ and a singlet around $\pu{2.4 ppm} \ \ce{(3H)}$.
- $\mathrm{^1H \ NMR}$ spectrum of diacetylferrocene consists of 3 signals: a triplet or multiplet around $\pu{4.8 ppm} \ \ce{(4H)},$ a triplet or multiplet around $\pu{4.5 ppm} \ \ce{(4H)},$ and a singlet around $\pu{2.4 ppm} \ \ce{(6H)}$.

Accordingly, the number of signals in each spectrum determine which compound it is. Since this is a Friedel-Crafts reaction, I assumed diacetylferrocene means acetylation on each cyclopentadiene ring (I also assumed you have separated each compound).